# How to set multiple SMTP server in android?

Tags: android, metadata

My question is how to set multiple SMTP server for sending mails in android like :
yahoo,hotmail,gmail,rediff any type of domain will worked while sending mail.Can anyone suggest any site or any idea ?

Please Help me,Thank you in advance.

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap .... I assume you will have to make your own class to manage those smtp's.

Comment: i have used same it is working for gmail only,bt not applicable for rest of the domains like yahoo,rediff etc...i have also changed the host as smtp.mail.yahoo.com instead of smtp.mail.gmail.com bt its not working gives Authorization failed erro....

Comment: **SMTP server = smtp.mail.yahoo.com, Security type = None, Server port = 587** Please try this for yahoo.

Answer (score 3):

### Here are tested settings for GMail, Yahoo! and Hotmail. Tested using Javax Mail port for Android.

```
smtp_host="smtp.gmail.com";
port=465;
tlsEnabled = true;
requiresAuth = false;
```

---

```
smtp_host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
port=465;
tlsEnabled = true; // false is OK as well
requiresAuth = true;  // false is OK as well
// login can have yahoo.com suffix OR not
```

---

```
smtp_host="smtp.live.com";
port=587;
tlsEnabled = false;
requiresAuth = true;
```